# Human readable memory sizes in top?

Tags: arch-linux, top

Is there an option in `top` to show memory sizes in human readable format?

Example:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                            
3960 phil      20   0 1347280 383112  30316 S   0.0  9.5   6:59.45 firefox
```

It would be nicer to show RES as 374m (instead of 383112).

I'm currently using Arch Linux. Ubuntu seems to use human readable representations by default.

(I tried `man top` but could not find the option. Maybe I missed it.)

Comment: It depends how it was compiled it seems. Some distro (RHEL6) top -M seems to do the job but for archlinux check that https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157103

Comment: @slm this is not a dupe. "Human-readable" doesn't mean "always display in MB". "Human-readable" means select the scale (B/KB/MB/GB/TB) dynamically depending on the amount.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

You can switch the memory unit by pressing `e`. `E` will select the memory unit in the *top* summary bar.

Use `W` to permanently write your configuration to /home/user/.toprc and see also `?` for more configuration options.

Comment: "Unknown command - try 'h' for help"

Comment: Ancient versions of `top` do not support command `e`. At least procps-ng version 3.3.9 supports it just fine.

Comment: This is not a valid solution to the question.  There is no option for human-readable units.  Everything ends up using the same scale, which you need to manually change, which is very inconvenient.  Compare to `free -h` which just chooses the correct units based on the magnitude of the value.

Comment: You are my hero!